# Mailmerge single image into a Word Document based on a cell value

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

I'd like to include an image into a mail merged word document based on the presence of a single value in a column which contains several values.

e.g. if the cell contains the value BOB insert image, if it contains any other value then do nothing.

Most of the {INCLUDEPICTURE} functionality seems built around including a different image based on a filename matching a cell value.

```
{INCLUDEPICTURE} "MERGEFIELD Selection_identifier).png"\*
MERGEFORMAT \d }
```

Works provided I translate selection_identifer in the spreadsheet itself, but there has to be a better way. There seems to be little information about this particular usecase online.

Comment: You would include your INCLUDETEXT field nested as truetext in an IF Field testing for the value of your code field. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#IF_field

Comment: @jonsson post this as the answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only using a single image and it does not vary between merges, you should probably just use

```
{ IF "{ MERGEFIELD Selection_identifier }" = "BOB" "<the_image>" }
```

where <the_image> is a copy of the actual image, sized how you want, pasted between those quotation marks. In that case, there would be no need for an `INCLUDEPICTURE` field or a reference to an external image file.

As usual, *all* the `{}` have to be the special field code brace pairs that you can insert on Windows Desktop Word using Carl-F9 or similar.